# Entered Fields should not be cleared with alert box is displayed in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to display a message if the amount entered greater than 5000 alert box or echo messsage "Enter a pan card no" as to be displayed when I click on submit button. In my code Message gets displayed but all the fields which data has been already entered gets cleared. I dont want the data which is entered to get cleared.
Here is the code.

```
    <?php

    include_once "db.php";

        if(isset($_POST['submit']))    {


                $amount  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["amount"]);
                $firstname=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["firstname"]);

                $phone=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["phone"]);
                $address=mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST["address"]));

                $pan=mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST["pan"]));
                $query= mysql_query("INSERT INTO payment (amount,selector1,firstname,lastname,email,phone,address,country,state,pan)VALUES('$amount','$selector1','$firstname','$lastname','$email','$phone','$address','$country','$state','$pan') ") or die(mysql_error()); 
                if($amount>="5000")
                {

    echo "Enter Pan Card No";       
                }           
                else {
                $id=mysql_insert_id();



    $_SESSION['sess_user'] = $id;
    $_SESSION['lastname'] = $lastname;
    $_SESSION['address']=$address;
    header("Location:successreg.php");          
            }
            }
    ?>  
<form action="" method="post" name="payment">
    <div class="w3l-user">

                    <input type="text" name="amount"  placeholder="&#x20B9; My Contribution" required="">
                </div>              



                        <input type="text"  name="firstname" placeholder="Firstname"   required="">

                        <input type="text"  name="pan" placeholder="Pan Card No" >
                </div>

                    <div class="btn">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit"   value="REGISTER"/>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You need to save the user data and in case validation fails on the server end, pass the data to the form so that you can repopulate those fields. In your code I do not see you passing data that user has already entered.

Comment: Don't use the deprecated and insecure **mysql*-functions**. They have been **deprecated** since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. You are wide open to **[SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)** and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: Then really, you should use AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to show values, after for submission you should get values from `$_POST` and use them in input values:

```
$firstname = '';
if(isset($_POST['submit']))    {
// write below line after `if`
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
```

Now, change your HTML to:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Firstname" required="" value="<?php echo $firstname; ?>">
```

For Radio buttons:

```
$firstRadio = $secondRadio = '';
if(isset($_POST['submit']))    {
// if first radio is selected which you will know from $_POST['firstRadio']
    $firstRadio = 'selected';
```

And in HTML:

```
<input type='radio' <?php echo $firstRadio;?> value=1 name='firstRadio' />
```

Comment: Its working fine.. If I have a radio button how will i display the selected value.

Comment: For radio, you will have to see which one is selected and based on that you will have to add `selected` attribute for that radio.

Comment: How to add selected?